# CLR Assembly in SQL Server Error "Timeout Exceeded" when executed in stored procedure, runs fine in new query window

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, timeout, sqlclr

I have this stored procedure, we'll call "wrapper", that calls another procedure to build an XML message then executes a CLR Assembly to send that XML message to a web service. The web service should then return a message saying success or failure. The issue is, the assembly is exceeding its timeout value. The issue appears to lie with the parameter that holds the XML message itself. 
Here is how that parameter is declared within the "wrapper" stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @v_vchInXML  XML,
        @v_vchOutXML XML
```

I have another procedure that generates the XML and returns it as an OUTPUT to the "wrapper" procedure. I then set it to another parameter, for logging, then pass the new parameter to the assembly procedure. The example is below, the parameters in question are surounded by ***.

```
EXECUTE usp_create_web_service_xml 
        @in_vchWhID, 
        @in_vchOrderNumber, 
        @v_nShipmentSeq, 
        ***@v_vchOutXML OUTPUT***, 
        @v_vchOutCode OUTPUT, 
        @v_vchOutMsg OUTPUT

SET ***@v_vchInXML*** = @v_vchOutXML;

EXECUTE usp_web_service_call_clr 
***@v_vchInXML***,
@v_vchURL,
@v_nTimeout, --Set to 8000 ms
@v_xmlHeader, --Set to ''
@v_nResponseTimeMS OUTPUT, 
@v_vchOutXML OUTPUT
```

If I were to replace the `@v_vchInXML` with the actual XML message in ticks in the stored procedure, the assembly runs fine and I get a return message back from the web service. For example.

```
EXECUTE usp_web_service_call_clr 
'<requests> username="ME"</requests>',
@v_vchURL,
@v_nTimeout, 
@v_xmlHeader, 
@v_nResponseTimeMS OUTPUT, 
@v_vchOutXML OUTPUT
```

Even if I were to set the parameter just before the execute like so, it will succeed.

```
SET @v_vchInXML = '<requests> username="ME"</requests>'

EXECUTE usp_web_service_call_clr 
@v_vchInXML,
@v_vchURL,
@v_nTimeout, 
@v_xmlHeader, 
@v_nResponseTimeMS OUTPUT, 
@v_vchOutXML OUTPUT
```

I cant figure out for the life of me why it is failing without having to hard code values, which will of course not work dynamically. What drives me nuts is that I had this working about a month and a half ago, with the exact code and all worked well.

Here is the execute block for the CLR Assembly.

```
ALTER DATABASE AADTEST SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT [name] 
    FROM sys.assemblies 
    WHERE [name] = N'HttpXmlClr'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [HttpXmlClr]
    FROM [**SUPER LONG ASSEMBLY STRING I REMOVED FOR SPACE PURPOSES**]
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_web_service_call_clr]
        @in_vchXMLRequest               XML
    ,@in_vchURL                     NVARCHAR(100)
    ,@in_nTimeout                   INT
    ,@in_xmlHTTPHeaders             XML
    ,@out_xmResponseTimeMS          INT             OUTPUT
    ,@out_xmlResponse               XML             OUTPUT
    --END OF COMMON INPUTS
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [HttpXmlClr].[StoredProcedures].[XmlRequest]
GO
```

Here is the response I get back from the assembly.

```
<error><method>main</method><message>timeout exceeded</message></error>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It could be any number things. Perhaps the size of the xml is very large? Perhaps your clr code is in an endless loop, or just taking a long time? It could be parameter sniffing, it could be....All anybody can do with such little detail is speculate.

Comment: John, are you 100% that the value of `@v_vchInXML` is `<requests> username="ME"</requests>`? You might want to do a `PRINT @v_vchInXML;` just before the `EXECUTE usp_web_service_call_clr` to be sure. Also, can you try changing `@v_vchInXML` to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or even `NVARCHAR(4000)` instead of `XML`? Just to rule out the issue being the datatype. When you pass in the literal it's not XML at that point. But, when you tested by setting the variable value first it is XML so not entirely sure it will help, but it at least will help narrow the issue down a little. And the `PRINT` will help.

Comment: Also, why is the Assembly set to `UNSAFE`? And why are you setting `TRUSTWORTHY ON`? Neither of those is advisable, and `TRUSTWORTHY` especially can cause issues.

Comment: Sean, What other detail are you looking for exactly? I doubt the CLR is an infinite loop since executing it works outside of the procedure.

Solomon, the value of `@v_vchInXML` is NOT `<requests> username="ME"</requests>`. It is much longer. I made it shorter to keep the post smaller, and the data in the message is sensitive. The XML is long, but this worked with longer XMLs. I have tried putting `PRINT` and `SELECT` to see the value of the field in many places before the assembly. As for changing the  datatype to NVARCHAR(MAX), that wont help because what is expected in the assembly is XML

Comment: John: good that you have confirmed that the value being passed-in is 100% what is expected. Is that the _exact same_ value that you hard-coded in one of your tests? Is this the only value that causes this behavior? Yes, I know that the .NET method expects `SqlXml`, but my point is that it will be implicitly converted to that, which is what happens when you passed in the string literal (which is a `VARCHAR(8000)` when the query is parsed). I am trying to rule out any issue with how the XML type itself is being passed in. Is the web service external or within your company?

Comment: John: what happens if you execute the "usp_create_web_service_xml" without executing the the actual clr call, you take the output value of "@v_vchOutXML" and then execute "usp_web_service_call_clr" with that value, does that work? Could it be that the "usp_create_web_service_xml" call blocks on something that the clr call needs access to?

Comment: John: How is it that you are certain that the value you are pasting in, either as a literal or to hard-code setting the variable, is _exactly_, byte-by-byte, the same as the variable is being set to when returned by `usp_web_service_call_clr`? Perhaps you can do something like `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @v_vchOutXML);` and make sure there are no "unexpected" / hidden / control characters in there.